# How long should deleting all records in a vertex take?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I have not found any metrics online to give me proper guidance on the following.

A single generic class, with 10 properties and 2 indexes.

The class has 10 million records.

How long should a `delete from targetclass` statement take?

The specs of the OrientDB server are reasonable. We have the db sitting on a highend san (purestorage). Debian 8 OS

Specs are

- NVMe based storage, 250K iOPS
- 16GB of ram
- 2 x 8 cores CPU

This operation takes well over 15 minutes for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you want to delete one or more classes of vertices and all the connected edges resides only on particular classes, you could use the `TRUNCATE CLASS` command against both vertex and edge classes by specifying the `UNSAFE` keyword. `TRUNCATE CLASS` is much faster than `DELETE VERTEX`, because it doesn't take in consideration the removal of the edges. Use `TRUNCATE CLASS` only when you are certain that there will not be broken edges on other vertices instances. Example of deleting all the instances of vertices classes `Email` and `Attachment` and the edge class that connect them `HasAttachment`:

```
  orientdb> TRUNCATE CLASS Email UNSAFE
  orientdb> TRUNCATE CLASS HasAttachment UNSAFE
  orientdb> TRUNCATE CLASS Attachment UNSAFE
```

Comment: Hi Lvca, thanks for your response. Same scenario as my original post, but instead, inserting records. If i do something like `create class tmp`, `insert into tmp from select from sourceclass` and the source class has 50k records, given the same properties from my original post, `A single generic class, with 10 properties and 2 indexes.`, what is the norm that this should take?